# Swipe on Gridlayout to show another GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a grid of buttons using GridLayout on my Android app. I want to swipe over this grid, so that another GridLayout is displayed. Is this possible using GridLayout? Any hint to where I should be looking for this would be great.
Edit: The GridLayout is a grid of buttons, that only occupy half the screen.

Comment: Try using a viewPager and each page is a GridLayout?

Comment: Will this also work for a grid of buttons, so I can swipe on this grid and show another grid of buttons? I am not exactly sure. I am trying to follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622942/how-to-swipe-only-a-portion-of-the-layout but I am not sure how to proceed with buttons.

Comment: each page of a viewPager can be a fragment which has its own layout file, so it can be anything.