# Android - Creating an Airbnb-like Horizontal Image Slider

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I'm looking to replicate airbnb's app image slider where you have one image at the top of a view that you can horizontally swipe and it automatically goes to the next image upon swipe. I created a horizontalscrollview but it doesn't quite have the right functionality. It doesn't flip from image to image, upon swipe it sort of scrolls along the image and eventually to the next image. I've googled around quite a bit and haven't seen a non deprecated solution.

Any ideas?

EDIT - adding some of my code per request:

Basically at a high level I'm pulling in imageURLs from my AWS database (in a different class not shown below) and then trying to load those URLs into a horizontalscrollview using Picasso.

```
//generic instructions to allow insertion of pictures into a horizontalimageslider

public View insertPhoto(String path){
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        Picasso.with(getActivity() ).load(path).into(imageView); //tried this but got errors when running > resize(layout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight()), also tried .fit() after .load image wouldn't load
        layout.addView(imageView);
        return layout;
            }

private class GetApartmentTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector,Long,Apartment >
//after a doInBackground

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Apartment apartment) {
//to get image URL from database to then use with Picasso to download the image

            mImageURLArraylist = mApartment.getApartmentImageArrayList();
            for (int z = 0 ;z<mImageURLArraylist.size(); z++) {
                mLinearLayout.addView(insertPhoto("http:" + mImageURLArraylist.get(z)) );
}
}}
```

in onCreateView method (alongside other things obviously)

```
mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.details_page_apartment_picture);
```

MyXML (relevant part)

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_page_apartment_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you show the images of what you have done already. Maybe I can do this for you.

Comment: added but for my particular case its a bit convoluted by pulling in from a class that does a jsonrequest to a database etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of frustration and some help getting over the finish line, the answer to swiping some part of the screen in this way is to use a viewpager.

Some great references:
[swipe some part of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969837/swipe-some-part-of-the-screen)
http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
[What is the role of " isViewFromObject (View view, Object object)" in FragmentStatePagerAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995446/what-is-the-role-of-isviewfromobject-view-view-object-object-in-fragmentst)

my working code is provided in another question I posted that got me over the finish line :) --
[Android ViewPager Won't Show Second Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828706/android-viewpager-wont-show-second-page/36828868#36828868)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the specifics of the airbnb app image slider, but it sounds like you could use flexslider.  It's basically a JQuery toolkit.  I have used it before in a website and it seems to have the functionality you are looking for.

https://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: unfortunately jquery doesn't work in android dev :( thanks for taking the time to reply however